# Stopping List traversal as soon as the transformation is carried on first element

Tags: list, haskell

Suppose, I have a `List` element with distinct numbers: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and I want to change the value `2` to `9` in the List.

I can acheive this using a simple function:

`map (\x -> if x == 2 then 9 else x) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

But performance wise, I think there is no need to traverse the entire list as the elements are distinct. Is there any other higher order function for doing the same without doing the entire list traversal ?

I know this can be solved using an explicit recursion but I was just wondering if this problem can be solved using any existing higher order function in an efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following if you'd like to avoid explicit recursion:

```
modifyFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
modifyFirst p f xs = concat [a, map f (take 1 b), drop 1 b]
    where (a, b) = break p xs

modifyFirst (==2) (const 9) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] === [1, 9, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This is also very inefficient (because `concat`enating lists is inefficient) in case the searched element appears late in a long list.

Comment: @Frerich Raabe: How to you propose to modify the selected element without traversing the elements that precede it? This is a linked list. And no, that's not necessarily inefficient - if the consumer of the resulting list ends up not needing to go that far, the entire update operation will be skipped. That's the advantage of lists in a lazy language.

Comment: Or you could do this:

    modifyFirst p f xs = concat [a, map f c, d]
      where
        {(a, b) = break p xs;
        (c, d) = splitAt 1 b}

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: "concat [a, b, c]" is just "foldr (==) [a, b, c]" which is "a ++ b ++ c". I could have written the other way I guess, but concat's not particularly inefficient here.

Comment: @Yitz The `concat` invocation effectively performs `a ++ b ++ c`, each `(++)` invocation requires to traverse to the end of its left-hand argument. However, I think this problem can be solved by first building the new left-hand list (ending in the new character) and then appending the remainder to that, i.e. with a single `(++)` call. In the example given in this question, that would be '(1 : 9 : []) ++ [3,4,5]`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: that's not right; `a ++ b ++ c` associates as `a ++ (b ++ c)`, and it should be apparent from the definition of `++` that we consume the elements of `a` lazily (and after that the elements of `b` and so on). Left associative concatentation does incur a quadratic overhead but `concat` is right associative.

Comment: @AndrásKovács: Aaah, thanks for the explanation! Indeed, I assumed that it would be `(a ++ b) ++ c`. So, now I'd like to take everything I said back and claim the opposite. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For example, we could do next:

```
modifyFirst _ _ [] = []
modifyFirst f y (x:xs) = if f x 
   then (y:xs) 
   else x : modifyFirst f y xs
```

But we can do this with library function:

```
import Data.List(span)

modifyFirst f y xs = nonF ++ newTail
 where (nonF,withF) = span f xs
       newTail = if null withF then [] else y : tail withF
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this isn't exactly what you asked, but I feel I must mention it anyway....

If you have a group of distinct elements, you might be better off storing them in a Data.Set.  You can then modify one element in the set like this

```
modify x x' theSet = if member x theSet then (insert x' $ delete x set) else theSet
```

This will happen in log n time (as opposed to the linear time you get with the list).

You can even convert a list to a set (using fromList) and then use this function, although there is an n * log n penalty to doing this, so it only makes sense if you have to run the conversion routine repeatedly (ie- if the set is being used like a database, constantly being updated....  This conversion is kind of like indexing a column in a database, which you would only do if you planned on looking up on that value often).

If you are only making the change once, don't bother converting to a set....  For that matter, why would you be worrying about performance in that case anyway? :)